# Seeing questions that actually have this tag

Tags: support, tags

If you go [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags?page=6&tab=popular) and scroll to the bottom, you'll find this tag: [braces](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/braces).

This tag is a synonym of [balanced-string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balanced-string), and rightfully so, as is [brackets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brackets).

I can't seem to figure out how to see questions tagged with [braces](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/braces) and [brackets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brackets), though. (That is, assuming there are any, which the link above certainly seems to say there are questions with these tags).

I just finished obliterating [shortest-time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortest-time) by retagging questions tagged with that tag to [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), of which [shortest-time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortest-time) is (was) a synonym. I found these questions by going [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), and then pressing <kbd>CTRL-F</kbd> and typing `shortest-time`. This strategy doesn't seem to work for [braces](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/braces) and [brackets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brackets), though, whose questions should obviously have [balanced-string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balanced-string) instead.

How can I see questions tagged with the *actual tag* [braces](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/braces), and not [balanced-string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balanced-string) of which [braces](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/braces) is a synonym?

Comment: I'm pretty sure when a tag synonym is added, all the instances of the synonym are replaced with the new tag, so I don't think this is possible. In the case you would have to do this, it probably means the synonym shouldn't of been made a synonym...

Comment: @Downgoat Well, there were questions tagged `shortest-time` after it was made a synonym of `fastest-code`, so now I'm more confused

Comment: @Downgoat http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/487/revisions and http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/3018/revisions

Comment: There aren't any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to find challenges with tags which are now synonymised?

You've probably noticed that you can't just search for a synonym, e.g. `[time]` (which is a synonym of [date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date), but still has some questions tagged with it. It is possible to find challenges which are tagged with synonyms of a certain parent, but not the parent itself with the following search query:

```
[date] -[date]
```

[Test it here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date+-date) Note that this turns up only three challenges with the [time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time) tag although four exist. I'm assuming the fourth one has both [date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) and [time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time), so it won't be found by this query. I don't know of a good way to find these using the search.

#### How does synonym renaming work?

When a synonym is created, old challenges won't be retagged automatically. That's why challenges with [time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time), [calendar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar) and [shortest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shortest-code) still exist. However, once the synonym is created, any attempt to use the tag will automatically be renamed.

In the case of [braces](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/braces), [brackets](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brackets) and [parentheses](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parentheses), I added these pre-emptively, so no challenges ever used them.

You can see whether any challenges still have a synonym, [you can visit the synonyms page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) (no privileges required), which shows how often a tag is still use.

#### Cleaning up synonyms

As for your actual goal of cleaning up all the uses of the old tag, that's honourable, but I don't think it's necessary. The old tag works like the new tag for all intents and purposes. Searching for either brings up all challenges with both tags. There is no separate tag page for the old tag any more. Using the old tag automatically turns into a new tag.

That said, there's also no good reason to keep the old tag around. But for getting rid of it, there's a much better solution than painstakingly trying to find all the challenges that still use it and then retag them one by one: moderators can merge tags. Even quite conveniently straight from the tag synonyms list. Not only is that a lot less effort, it also doesn't create a revision in the affected challenges and doesn't bump all of them to the front page. So if you think some old synonym should be cleaned up, just let a moderator know in chat or post a request here on meta.

- [Further reading on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/201409)